# When I add a Google Contact, if there is an existing photo, where does it come from?

Tags: google-account, google-contacts, google-voice

In a few instances, I have added a new contact on my phone, which is synched to Google Contacts. When viewing in Contacts, there is an existing photo associated with that person.

Where is this photo coming from? It used to be linked to the person's Google+ account, but that doesn't exist anymore. Is this a remnant of that service? Or an indication that they have Google Voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photo could come from Gmail or from https://myaccount.google.com

NOTE: Recently Google announced that both places will use the same photo.

Reference

- [Set profile picture for Gmail and all Google apps](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/10/updates-to-google-profile-pictures.html)